# Page Table Registers and Cache

Tags: operating-system, page-tables

I just learned about memory management and I am currently trying to figure out what Page Table is. Per my understanding, Page Table is a data structure that works just like hash tables, used to map and connect both logical and physical memory address in an Operating System.

We will need one register to determine the location of a page table of a process. But how many registers do we need to determine the location of a multilevel page table, for example a two and three level page table? How do you determine it?

Also, how will cache (L1-L3) in the processor affect memory reference access to page table? Will the majorities miss or hit? Why does it happen?

I tried to find references for this, but it leads me to TLB and I haven't learned about it yet. Might say that I am really beginner in OS. Help :)

Comment: You only ever need one register which points to the top level page table (or page directory).  The entries in that table are pointers to the next-level tables, and so on, until the lowest level which contains the actual physical memory addresses.

Comment: @NateEldredge does it apply to the multi level page table? So even two and three level page table only has one register? And what about the second question?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean: one register to point to the top-level table; no further registers needed for any additional levels, no matter how many.

Comment: Your second question should really go in a separate post.  It may have different answers for different architectures.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see. I have never thought that it was really that simple. Thanks! Will start a new post two get to the bottom of the second question.

Comment: You really might want to learn about TLBs first though, which are not that complicated a concept, just a different kind of cache.  Any answer you get is likely to mention them. They mean that the page tables get accessed a lot less than you would guess, and so whether they get kept in normal memory cache is not as relevant.

Comment: @NateEldredge I did read the materials about TLB but I think that this question is a lot more opinion-based as I think it is, because truthfully our lecturer hasn't taught anything regarding TLBs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Nate's answer, we only need one register at the top level of the table, and the entries in the table are pointers to the next levels so there won't be any needs of more than one register in any level of page table.

Comment: refer to this for the second question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66451938/page-table-and-cache-hit-rates